# ASP.NET MVC 4 OAuthWebSecurity is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, .net-4.5

In my ASP.NET mvc 4 application, I tried to implement **Account/ExternalLogin**
i configured,

1. Microsoft(Windows Live),
2. Facebook 
   with ClientID and ClientSecret and enabled GoogleOpenAuth
   unfortunately nothing is working.

   Url call: provider=microsoft&**sid**=95b923de889e4a4db6861c98fafb42a3&code=f85770b1-266b-3abd-4c46-8d62fe3014dc">http://mydomain.com/account/externallogincallback?**provider**=microsoft&**sid**=95b923de889e4a4db6861c98fafb42a3&code=f85770b1-266b-3abd-4c46-8d62fe3014dc

   AuthenticationResult result =      OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));

All OpenAuth calls are failing, Google will return with authentication false,
Facebook and Microsoft(Windows Live) gives 400 bad request responses.

Can any one suggest how to resolve this?

More details:
These are the DLL I used

1. C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio
   2012\Projects\myProject\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.4.0.3.12153\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll
2. C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio
   2012\Projects\myProject\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.4.0.3.12153\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll
3. C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio
   2012\Projects\myProject\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Core.4.0.3.12153\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll
4. C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio
   2012\Projects\myProject\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Core.4.0.3.12153\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll
5. C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Visual Studio    2012\Projects\myProject\packages\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.4.0.3.12153\lib\net40-full\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll

Web.config

```
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" >
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="WebMatrix.Data, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <add assembly="WebMatrix.WebData, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

Found the problem:
Well i figured it out, I had a custom function triggered at application start, that will enforce the full url to lower case and when OAuth token is called back to Facebook, token value is also lower cased, that was creating problem. glad that i could find it out:)

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure what's the cause without seeing real code, but double check that the return url that you pass to RequestAuthentication() is exactly the same as the one you pass to VerifyAuthentication()

Comment: Well i figured it out, I had a custom function triggered at application start, that will enforce the full url to lower case and when oAUth token is called back to Facebook, token value is also lower cased, that was creating problem. glad that i could find it out:)